# JQuery mobile bug with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, scrolltop

In the following link I have attached a sample of my source code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xY7tx/2381/

I have a list of 34 items when you press down the keyboard and you reach the 10th item, it would successfully `scrollTop` to 11th element. But when you keep pressing down and when you reach 20th item, with my code it supposed to `scrollTop` to 21th item but it isn't.

To reproduce the bug please keep pressing down on keyboard and pay attention to the 20th ---> 21th item which is not desirable (and compare it with 10th --> 11th item change which is desirable).

If i have done any mistake, my apologies and please show me in the source code what change should I make so that in change of 20th to 21th item, it would `scrollTop` as well. Thanks!

Edit: Thanks to ezanker. with his answer , i can now scrollTop to the item of 21th , but still there is a problem when i want to scrollTop t the 31th item , still it isn't working with the current code . please keep pressing down on keyboard until 31th item , you would see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting

```
var container = $('div'),
```

but jQuery Mobile automatically creates a page div to wrap around your code if you do not explicitely provide the div. Change it to

```
var container = $('#listAddr'),
```

Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xY7tx/2382/)**

Comment: with your changes 20th to 21th item changes works as desire , but when i keep pressing down , 30th to 31th item doesn't scrollTop as desire. please keep pressing down until you reach 31th item , there is still a problem with your updated code there.

Comment: @Jack, that's because you only have 34 items. You can't scroll beyond the height of the list. I suppose you couls add empty items or an empty div below the list...